# Is this understanding of VkDescriptorPoolCreateInfo.pPoolSizes correct?

Tags: vulkan

In Vulkan, I understand that a descriptor pool is used to allocate descriptor sets of some layout for use in a shader, but in the `VkDescriptorPoolCreateInfo` passed to `vkCreateDescriptorPool`, there is a field `pPoolSizes` that takes a bunch of objects containing a descriptor type and a number.

The documentation seems somewhat vague, but is this saying that a given descriptor pool can only have a certain, predetermined amount of each type of descriptor allocated from it in descriptor sets? If so, how do I determine how many I will need beforehand? What happens if it runs out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding of descriptor pools is correct.

> If so, how do I determine how many I will need beforehand?

That's up to you and your application's needs.

If your application needs to be completely flexible and freeform, then you will need to create descriptor pools dynamically as needed. If your application has greater foreknowledge of what the scene will look like, then your application will need fewer of such gymnastics.

Many serious Vulkan applications try to avoid having the number of descriptor sets be based on the number of objects in the scene. Push constants and/or dynamic UBO/SSBO descriptors allow different per-object state to be used without changing the descriptor itself. Textures for lots of objects can be bundled together into array textures, or depending on the hardware, arrays of textures.

In a perfect world, all meshes of a type (say, skinned meshes) could be rendered with the *exact same* descriptor set, using some per-object state to fetch the right matrix/texture data for that object.

But that's how they render. Such applications have firm control over the kinds of objects they render, what per-object data looks like, and so forth. Other applications may have different needs.

Vulkan is a tool; how you use it is entirely up to you.

> What happens if it runs out?

Then you cannot allocate more descriptors from that pool. If you need to allocate another descriptor set, you will need to create another pool.

Answer (score 0):

My approach was to have a class that initially allocates N of the descriptor, and if it runs out, it'll create another pool with N*2 entries. It'll keep doubling in size. It uses a simple linked lists and when it comes to allocating, it just tries the first one, and then moves onto the next if it's full.

That's all pretty inefficient, so I also had my code fire an assert if it ever had to create a second pool, that way I can make sure I choose a value of N that's big enough so that the retail version should never have to do it (but if it does somehow manage to due to some unforeseen set of circumstances, it'll still render correctly).

At the time, I remember cursing the spec and wishing descriptor pools would auto grow like command pools do. Still I imagine there's a good reason that they are like they are.